# Understanding differentiability in functions of two variables

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

In functions of single variable we would say that a function $f$ is differentiable at $x=a$ if:

$\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(a+h) - f(a)} {h} $ 
Exists and equals a real number which becomes $f'(a)$ . And this leads(and it is clear how) to an equivalent definition :

There exists a function $\epsilon(h)$  that tends to $0$ as $h$ tends to $0$ and 
$f(a+h) =f(a) + hf'(a) + h\epsilon(h) $.

Now in my textbook the idea of differentiability was introduced by saying that we say that $f$ is differentiable at $(a, b)$ if there exists an $\epsilon(h,k)$ that tends to $0$ as $||(h,k)||$ ($||.||$ is a defined norm on the domain) tends to $(0,0)$ such that 
$f(a+h,b+k) =f(a,b) +hf'_x(a, b) +kf'_y(a, b) +||(h,k)|| \epsilon(h, k) $.

My problem is that I do understand the graphical meaning of differentiability for one variable, but for two variables does this definition cover $\mathbf only$ the existence of the partial derivatives of f at this point? What is the intuition behind this definition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea behind is that, around your point, the function is approximately linear. Namely, if $h$ and $k$ are small increments from $(a,b)$ and we call $(x,y)=(a+h,b+k)$, then
$$
f(x,y)=f(a+h,b+k)\approx f(a,b)+Ah+Bk=f(a,b)+A(x-a)+B(y-b)
$$
and the error is much smaller that $h$ or $k$ in size. This condition forces the partial derivatives to exist, and they should be equal to $A$ and $B$ respectively.

Geometrically, we are requiring that the graph of the function had a tangent plane (or hyperplane in higher dimensions). Having partial derivatives is a weaker restriction. Differentiability requires linearity in all directions, while the mere existence of the partial derivatives means that your function is linear in one variable if you keep the other one fixed.